# ExecuteScalar Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to use `ExecuteScalar` to return a `uniqueidentifier`. However when I try and run it, I get this error:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
        Dim id As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("id")
    Dim file As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("file")
    connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString.ToString
    Dim SQLConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    SQLConnection.Open()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GetFile", SQLConnection)

    Dim param1 As New SqlParameter()
    param1.ParameterName = "@id"
    param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier
    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    param1.Value = id

    Dim param2 As New SqlParameter()
    param2.ParameterName = "@file"
    param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier
    param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    param2.Value = file

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "GetFile"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2)

    cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    If cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString = Nothing Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    Else
        HttpContext.Current.Session("fileguid") = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End If
```

The stored procedure has these two parameters defined:

```
    @id uniqueidentifier, 
@file uniqueidentifier
```

It is just using the two parameters to verify they exist on the same record.
The select statement is:

```
SELECT [file] FROM [dbo].[files] WHERE [cid] = @id AND [file] = @file
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: You're calling ExecuteScalar twice!

Comment: Am I? I though ExecuteScalar.ToString would just use the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id and file are strings, make them into GUIDs

```
var idGuid = new System.Guid(id);
var fileGuid = new System.Guid(file);
```

And pass them to the stored procedure

```
param1.Value = idGuid;
...
param2.Value = fileGuid;
```